# STUN Binding (ICE connectivity check) Failing for Specific Peer

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn

We have a TURN fleet that has presence with the AWS Regions `US-EAST-1` and `US-WEST-2`.

A client in the Ukraine is trying to connect to a peer in the United Kingdom. Both the client and the peer are behind a symmetric NAT.

The client does not have access to TURN credentials.
The peer does have access to TURN credentials.

The result is:

client:

```
host
server reflexive
```

peer:

```
host
server reflexive
relay
```

Our TURN fleet creates permissions in IP addresses ONLY, and ignores the port variations.

#### Success case: Client initiates a call through `US-EAST-1`.

1. Client gathers its host, and server reflexive candidate. Sends them to peer.
2. Peer receives the clients candidates, and gathers its own host, server reflexive and relay candidate. Sends them to the client.
3. The client sends a STUN binding to the relay transport address.
4. The TURN relay sees the request, attaches an `XOR-PEER-ADDRESS` to it and forwards it to the client via a DATA indication.
5. The client sees the request, generates a response, and sends it to the relay via a SEND indication.
6. The relay accepts and forwards the message to the peer.
7. The peer unwraps the `XOR-PEER-ADDRESS`, determining it to be a `peer reflexive` candidate and sets the active pair as `local: prflx | remote: relay`.
8. Media flows, everyone is happy.

#### Failure case: Client initiates a call through `US-WEST-2`.

Steps 1 to 6 occur as they did above.

7. The peer never receives the response from the TURN server containing the peer reflexive candidate in the `XOR-PEER-ADDRESS`.
8. Since it is a symmetric NAT, the call fails.

This only happens to a particular peer, as we see thousands of prflx / relay calls happening in `US-WEST-2` even at this very moment. I don't have any reason to believe that the TURN server failed to send the response.

Security groups for outgoing are fully permissive (for IPv4/6) and are identical.

```
0.0.0.0/0
::/0
```

The config files in both regions are identical. As far as my exhaustive search has taken me, the only difference between the two calls is the AWS Region that the calls are made through. I could be mistaken, but I've combed through every little detail I could think of.

I've even tested `US-EAST-1` and `US-WEST-2` myself through a symmetric NAT and was able to establish a `prflx-relay` call.

Has anyone encountered this before?

---

Binding Request (peer -> TURN)

```
1094    5.262769    192.168.1.202   TURN_IP_ADDRESS STUN    
170 Binding Request user: 0kZJvRw4xieMyZWtgrfSvGh6EzfhRzxP:5Vi8
```

TURN to Client DATA indication:

```
3942    8.729590    TURN_IP_ADDRESS  192.168.1.202   STUN    
150 Binding Success Response XOR-MAPPED-ADDRESS: 1.2.3.4:9976 user: ttsEVBZnkpBftWENErHh+3HkiEj3xoU2:8/DZ
```

Client Receives message:

```
3272    7.757723    TURN_IP_ADDRESS 192.168.88.108  STUN    
250 Data Indication XOR-PEER-ADDRESS: 1.2.3.4:9976
```

Client Creates a permission:

```
CreatePermission Request XOR-PEER-ADDRESS: 1.2.3.4:9976 with nonce realm: amazonaws.com user: { USERNAME }
```

Client responds:

```
3358    7.930904    192.168.88.108  TURN_IP_ADDRESS STUN    
186 Send Indication XOR-PEER-ADDRESS: 1.2.3.4:9976
```

TURN to Peer response:

```
nothing received by the peer
```

Client continues to receive DATA indications of:

```
3272    7.757723    TURN_IP_ADDRESS 192.168.88.108  STUN    
250 Data Indication XOR-PEER-ADDRESS: 1.2.3.4:9976
```

and continues to respond with:

```
3358    7.930904    192.168.88.108  TURN_IP_ADDRESS STUN    
186 Send Indication XOR-PEER-ADDRESS: 1.2.3.4: 9976
```

Eventually the call times out.

Comment: sounds like a permissions issue. Can you run with permissions disabled (in coturn that is controlled via `server-relay`; note the "danger" warning)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. I think my next step is to get see if I can netcat to the peer from the relay. I can also monitor the packets leaving the relay through a few means to ensure that the message is indeed sent. I haven't sniffed the outgoing packets - but as I said, this fleet is used by thousands of calls per hour... I doubt its not sending the UDP message.

Comment: Oh sorry I should also mention. I've put a call through this fleet myself through a symmetric NAT. The prflx candidate was discovered successfully and the call occurred as normal. So I believe its peer related.

Comment: you might want to check how the clients stun server is configured -- does it point to the same server that the peer is using for TURN? Otherwise this could fail with a NAT that does a different mapping for the different target addresses (i.e. the client gets mapped to IP A for STUN but IP B for TURN -- but the peer has only added a permission for IP A)

Comment: I can verify that the peer is able to send a BINDING request through TURN, and over to the client. I have wireshark logs for both legs. Let me update my question with some additional info.

Comment: Philipp - I added some more info to the tail end of my question. Basically what happens is that the client receives the `XOR-PEER-ADDRESS`, and then responds. This happens over and over again until the call fails. On the peer side, it is receiving nothing. It just keeps sending BINDINGS and the client keeps responding to them (but with the response never making it back to the peer). Thus the peer never discovers its peer-reflexive address and the call fails.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say its a problem with the peer's network. Although it is weird that it worked in `US-EAST-1` but failed in `US-WEST-2`. Additionally, the peer is able to reach TURN and get a packet over to the client - but cannot get a response. Which is well, even weirder, still.

Comment: Philipp - I should also add. When TWO relays are in the call, it succeeds. i.e., TURN relaying to TURN works just fine. Its only failing for the single relay case.

Comment: humm... in that case you may encounter one of the weird "we let outgoing udp through but block all incoming udp" VPNs. They're rare but exist.

Comment: Thats my suspicion. So very odd... Thank you for relaying some thoughts.